# Custom options Magento

Tags: magento

I am struggeling with Magento custom options.

In Magento you can add custom options at a Simple product. With this option an attribute like "color" can be added. Before the customer want to add the product to his cart, he first select the custom option "color". The price can change at every color.

But the options are very individual. I want the options are dependent on each other.

Something like this:

```
lenght = 100cm -> wood type: 1 = 120 euro total-> color: green = 140 euro total
                                               -> color: grey = 150 euro total
                  wood type: 2 = 130 euro total-> color: green = 150 euro total
                                               -> color: grey = 160 euro total

lengt = 120cm  -> wood type 1: = 130 euro total-> color: green = 160 euro total
                                               -> color: grey = 170 euro total
                  wood type 2: = 140 euro total-> color: green = 180 euro total
                                               -> color: grey = 190 euro total
```

A store that I know that use it is: 
http://www.zelfbouwmeubels.nl/tafels/eettafel/

And then select "SAMENSTELLEN".

Do i need an plugin for it or is there an default functionality in Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a configurable product instead of a simple product, and download a module that will use the selected simple product's pricing. Then you can individually manage each length/wood-type/colour option as an individual SKU and charge different prices for each.

Configurable products:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Module to do what you want:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products

Comment: I use the advanced product options plug-in at this moment. And it works. Thanks for help!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.